# Issue with function and MapThread

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to make a function that effects the operation:

```
{ a1, a2, ..., an } -> { {1, {a1}}, {2, {a2}}, ..., {n, {an}} }
```

I have defined my function to be:

```
x10 := MapThread[List, {{x6}, {list10}}, 1]
x6 = Range[Length[list10]]
list10 = {a, b, c, d, e}
Print[x10]
```

which gives the output:

```
{{{1,2,3,4,5},{a,b,c,d,e}}}
```

I think I might need to use the attribute HoldAll, but is anything else necessary to get the required output?

Comment: Make a standalone `MapThread` with your input explicitly inside and make sure your curly brackets are ok.

Comment: In both an after-the-fact and FWIW vein: Transpose[Flatten[x10, 1]] yields               {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}, {5, e}}

Answer (score 3):

```
x10 := MapThread[List, {x6, List /@ list10}]
x6 := Range[Length[list10]]
list10 = {a, b, c, d, e}
x10
```

> {{1, {a}}, {2, {b}}, {3, {c}}, {4, {d}}, {5, {e}}}

```
n = 5;
lst = Array[Symbol["a" <> ToString@#] &, n];
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], {#}} &, lst]
```

> {{1, {a1}}, {2, {a2}}, {3, {a3}}, {4, {a4}}, {5, {a5}}}

Also

```
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, List /@ lst]
MapIndexed[{#2.{1}, {#}} &, lst] (* thanks: Mr.Wizard *)
MapThread[List, {Range@n, List /@ lst}]
Thread[{Range @ n, List /@ lst}]
```

> {{1, {a1}}, {2, {a2}}, {3, {a3}}, {4, {a4}}, {5, {a5}}}

Comment: How about `MapIndexed[{#2.{1}, {#}} &, lst]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, that too works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something from the `Replace` family to tackle this, i.e.

```
i = 1;
Replace[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, x_ :> {i++, {x}}, 1]
```

> {{1, {a}}, {2, {b}}, {3, {c}}, {4, {d}}, {5, {e}}, {6, {f}}, {7, {g}}}